# Spring AOP: java.util.HashMap cannot be cast to SomeClass

Tags: java, spring, aop

When I used spring aop(aspectJ proxy-target-class="true"), List can receive the parameters from json but it shows that "java.util.hashmap cannot be cast to MyEntity". And I am using SSH framework. The codes are shwon below:

```
package com.yoyo.aspect;

@Aspect
@Component
@Scope("prototype")
@ParentPackage("json-default")
@Results({@Result(name="result", type="json", params={"root","dataMap"})})
public class LoggerAspect extends SuperAction{

@Autowired
private LoggerService loggerService;

//signature
@Pointcut("execution(String com.yogo.action.admin..*.*(..))")
public void adminLogger(){}

@Pointcut("execution(String com.yogo.action.enterprise..*.*(..))")
public void enterpriseLogger(){}

@Pointcut("execution(String com.yogo.action.product..*.*(..))")
public void productLogger(){}

@Around(value="adminLogger()||enterpriseLogger()||productLogger()")
public Object loggerAround(ProceedingJoinPoint pjp) throws Throwable{

    ServletRequestAttributes attr = (ServletRequestAttributes)RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes(); 
    HttpSession session=attr.getRequest().getSession(true);

    String className = pjp.getSignature().getDeclaringTypeName();

    Method method = ((MethodSignature)pjp.getSignature()).getMethod();
    String methodName = method.getName();

    Logger log = new Logger();

    log.setClassName(className);
    log.setMethodName(methodName);

    try {

        log.setResult("success");
        return pjp.proceed();

    } catch (Throwable throwable) {

        log.setResult("failure");
        return RESULT;

    } finally {

        if(session!=null&&session.getAttribute("AID")!=null){
            log.setAid((int)session.getAttribute("AID"));
            log.setDatetime(new Date());

            loggerService.save(log);
        }
    }

}
```

}

```
package com.yoyo.action.product.property;

@Controller
@Scope("prototype")
@ParentPackage("json-default")
@Namespace("/product")
@Results({@Result(name="result", type="json", params={"root","dataMap"})})
@InterceptorRefs({@InterceptorRef(value="json"), @InterceptorRef(value="defaultStack")})
public class AddOrUpdateProductPropertyAction extends SuperAction /*implements ModelDriven<ProductProperty>*/{

@Autowired
private ProductPropertyService productPropertyService;

private ProductProperty productProperty = new ProductProperty();
private List<ProductProperty> list;
private Product product;

public Product getProduct() {
    return product;
}

public void setProduct(Product product) {
    this.product = product;
}

public List<ProductProperty> getList() {
    return list;
}

public void setList(List<ProductProperty> list) {
    this.list = list;
}

/*@Override
public ProductProperty getModel() {
    return productProperty;
}*/

@Action(value="AddOrUpdateProductProperty")
public String addOrUpdateProductProperty() throws Throwable{

    int pid = product.getPid();

    try {

        if(pid!=0&&!"".equals(pid)){

            productProperty.setPid(pid);

            for(int i=0; i<list.size(); i++){
                productProperty.setPpid(list.get(i).getPpid());
                productProperty.setPkey(list.get(i).getPkey());
                productProperty.setPvalue(list.get(i).getPvalue());
                productProperty.setStatus(list.get(i).getStatus());
                productPropertyService.saveOrUpdate(productProperty);
            }

        }else{

            setErrorResult(2, "No Product ID");

        }

    } catch (Exception e){

        setErrorResult(1, e.getMessage());
        throw new Exception(e);

    }

    return RESULT;
}
```

}

And I post the json in the right format to this AddOrUpdateProductProperty(url):

```
{
"product":{
    "pid":"1"
    },
"list":[
    {
    "pkey": "",
    "pvalue":"45%",
    "status":1
    }]
}
```

the response saying(exception.getMessage):

```
{"msg":"java.util.HashMap cannot be cast to com.yogo.entity.ProductProperty","flag":1}
```

If I comment the AOP execution, everything runs well and all the data in "list" can be well received and written in mysql successfully.

```
//@Around(value="adminLogger()||enterpriseLogger()||productLogger()")
```

I also checked receiving the data in "list" using println. I found that it can receive it but cannot cast to MyEntity "ProductProperty":

```
System.out.println(list.get(i));
//this works

System.out.println(list.get(i).getPpid());
//this got error as above
```

I am not quite familiar with spring aop mechanism, anyone could help? Thank you so much!

Comment: typo:
System.out.println(list.get(i).getPpid());
//this got error as above

Comment: I have fixed your typo. You can always edit your own questions, there is no need to post comments instead of fixing it.

Comment: Furthermore, your code looks very chaotic and buggy. For instance, you return `RESULT` - where does that variable come from? Then you compare an `int` value to an empty `String`, which dies not make any sense. And so forth. But the most important issue is that you want to know why your `ProductProperty.getPpid()` does not work, but you are not showning the source code for that class. Please improve the question, ideally by providing an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). Then I will be glad to help you.